# Is there a way to store tab seperated values into a 2-d array

Tags: bash

I have been looking for a solution on this online but could not get much information (most multi-array examples are not being created from text docs) so here it goes. Say I have a script that reads in values from a text doc example.txt:

```
Tag1      Value1
Tag2      Value2
Tag3      Value3
```

Is there such a way where I can programmatically store Tag and Value into a 2-dimensional array so that it looks like:

```
arrayResult=[Tag1][Value1]
            [Tag2][Value2]
            [Tag3][Value3];
```

(excuse the syntax please). I would want this done preferably in bash rather than awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash does not do multi-dimensional arrays. Are you looking for an associative array?

```
declare -A arrayResult

while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do
    arrayResult["$key"]=$value
done < example.txt

for key in "${!arrayResult[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${arrayResult["$key"]}"
done
```

Requires bash version 4 for associative arrays.

Comment: Yes I am. I am doing it so that the program I am calling in my script which takes two parameters (one is for a tag, the other is for a value).

Comment: Note that it won't work for empty keys. `zsh` and `ksh93` can work around that by using `IFS=$'\t\t'`, not `bash`.